# Node js convert date to valid mssql date

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I'm using *node js* together with the [mssql package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) to create my API.

Here I want to call a *stored procedure* on my sql-server which takes `DATETIME` as parameter.

My Js code looks like that

```
const sql = require('mssql');

router.get('/getStuff', async (req, res) => {
    const pool = await new sql.ConnectionPool(DB_CONNECTION).connect();

    const date = moment().format('DD.MM.YYYY');

    const result = await pool.request()
            .input('Date', sql.DateTime, date)
            .execute('MY_Stored_Procedure');

    res.status(200).send(result.recordset);
}
```

Then I get the following error

> ERROR: {"code":"EPARAM","number":"EPARAM","originalError":{"message":"Validation failed for parameter 'Date'. Invalid date.","code":"EPARAM"},"name":"RequestError","precedingErrors":[]}

I also tried all *mssql* data types

- Date
- DateTime
- DateTime2

To complete it here is the beginning of the *stored procedure*

```sql
create procedure MY_Stored_Procedure(
    @Date DATETIME = null   
) as

set dateformat dmy;
...
```

Comment: Did you tried with international date format `yyyy-MM-dd` ?

Comment: Yes i did but this should not matter because i set `dateformat` to `dmy`.

Comment: You set the format inside the procedure. `@date` value is not affected by the server `dateformat`, it is provided by `mssql` js package. You can try passing a `varchar` value to the procedure and `cast` it into a Date, that way the dateformat will apply.